# Is there a way to follow answerers?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a way to follow answerers ? For example at present we have facility to follow tags like say "elementary number theory" . similarly is there a way to follow answerers .

Why I am asking this is some answerer's answers are all marvelous and we can learn a lot from their answers . Not only their answers for complex questions , but even the way some people tackle differently and logically even simple questions and make answers the simplest and this gives a huge scope for learning from their answers and thinking out of box and finally making us die-hard fans of their answers and way of thinking.I am actually a virtual student of a number of users here .

If there is a way for following please show .if not consider this as a feature request.